# How to convert html page to image file?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

i want to convert a Html page into image file. for this i used code

My Code :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    saveURLToImage("http://cg.nic.in/mahasamund/home.htm");

}
private void saveURLToImage(string url)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
    {
        string content = "";

        System.Net.WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
        System.Net.WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
        content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        //save to file
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(content);
        byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(content);
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(b);
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        img.Save(@"d:\pic.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        img.Dispose();
        ms.Close();
    }
}
```

when i am run this code and click on Button then error occurred i.e.

```
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
```

What is the problem?
How shall I do this?

Comment: I already have this need. In that time I used `PhantomJS`, an `*.exe` that open the page like a browser and you can take screen shots of this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have "\0" characters in your string and that is not a valid base64 character.

I would try to use:

```
content.Trim("\0");
```

before you are converting to base64

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(content);
```

It seems your **content** contains sth illegal. (Maybe some tag)
Try to encode it before passing to the FromBase64String method.